# What's my Gitlab password if it's linked to my Google account?

Tags: gitlab, gmail

When I try to push anything into my Gitlab repo, I'm being asked for a password, the thing is that I don't know if i'´s asking for my account password or a repository password. In either case I don't have a password for them because I was never prompted to create one.

I created my account by linking a Bitbucket account, which in turn is linked to my Gmail account.

Does Gitlab create a password for me automatically, like the username it creates off my email?

Answer (score 1):

If you create your GitLab account by linking a Bitbucket account, which in turn is linked to your Google account, then your GitLab account's password is the same as your Google password.

This is referred to as [Single sign-on (SSO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on):

> Single sign-on (SSO) is an authentication scheme that allows a user to log in with a single ID and password to any of several related, yet independent, software systems.

You could also use Google SSO to create an account on GitLab instead of using Bitbucket SSO.  This has several advantages:

- It's directly linked to your Google account, just like the Bitbucket account.
- Maintains a 1-1 relationship between Google SSO and third-party Git hosting services.
- There is one less SSO service you are dependent upon.  By using Bitbucket SSO you are reliant on both Google SSO and Bitbucket SSO when signing into GitLab.

In short, it makes more sense to use a single SSO service rather than multiple services.  Partially, that's where the name comes from.

Comment: hey! It actually didn´t work, but I went to the credential manager and saw that I have no credential for GIT, my question is I´m now adding the generic credential but what should I put on the network or internet adress?

Comment: You can change the bitbucket password and use it then.

Comment: I made some edits to the question and answer.  The password for your GitLab account is the same as your Bitbucket account.